# Actual expression for generic slaves cannot reference a signal

Tags: generics, port, vhdl

In Quartus I get following error message:

***Error (10795): actual expression for generic slaves cannot reference a signal***

The code has a component instantiation with generics like this:

```
architecture rtl of System is

    component spi_master
        generic(
             slaves  : INTEGER := 1;                                        
        port(clock   : IN  STD_LOGIC;                                                                                                        
             sclk    : BUFFER STD_LOGIC;                                      
             ss_n    : BUFFER STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(slaves - 1 DOWNTO 0);               
    end component spi_master;                                                  


    signal spi_slaves   : INTEGER := 1;


begin

    spi : component spi_master
        generic map(
            slaves  => 1,           
        )
        port map(clock   => clk_clk,
            sclk    => dac_sclk,
            ss_n    => slave_sel,
        );

end architecture rtl;
```

The error points to the line ***"generic map("***. What I found out is that I can not use ***"slaves"*** in the port declaration as well.

Questions:
- How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message is perfectly clear. Oddly, the code does not exhibit the error, so there's something you're not telling us. A Generic is essentially a compile time constant (actually elaboration time) so it cannot connect to a signal, whose value can vary at runtime.

Comment: This code doesn't show the problem to which Morten guessed the answer - "The problem probably is". It's chock full of syntax errors, that when corrected, and if an entity declaration and context clause are provided analyzes successfully without changing the declaration of constant spi_slaves.  Perhaps you could 'correct ' the code to demonstrate the actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does not match the problem description, since `slaves => 1` is OK, including reuse in the declaration `BUFFER STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(slaves - 1 DOWNTO 0)`.

The problem probably is that the failing code uses `slaves  => spi_slaves`, where `spi_slaves` is a signal, and that is illegal.

Change declaration of `spi_slaves` to:

```
constant spi_slaves : INTEGER := 1;
```

Comment: Yes you are right. With introducing the constant it solved my problem - thanks!

Comment: Aren't the extra `,`s after the last port and generic maps also an error? e.g. `slave_sel,` should be `slave_sel`?

Comment: @scary_jeff: Yes, the extra `,`s is a syntax error, along with a missing `)`, and probably other issues.  Btw. allowing an extra `,` has been suggested for future VHDL version, and is a feature in other languages like e.g. Python, but not yet legel in VHDL.